# Memory leak when using HttpWebRequest object in ASP.NET site

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory

This is my class:

```
public class HttpRequestHelper
    {
        public static string GetRequestText(string url, string method, string referer, string postData, int timeout = 50000, string userAgent = null, string proxy = null)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            request.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
            request.Method = method;
            request.Timeout = timeout;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proxy))
                request.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(proxy);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
            if (!userAgent.IsNullOrEmptyText())
            {
                request.UserAgent = userAgent;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(referer))
            {
                request.Referer = referer;
            }
            if (method == "POST")
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postData))
                {
                    request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
                    using (Stream writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
                        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
                        writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    }
                }
                else request.ContentLength = 0;
            }
            string result = string.Empty;
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        result = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Normal my site take around 170mb memory (around 40k records in database). But when i call `GetRequestText` function the memory up to 1Gb memory. I dont know why? Any idea or solution for this ?

Thanks advance!

Comment: Well how big is `postData`, and how big is the response?

Comment: Hi Jon, thank for your interest. No post data. Im using GET method. Reponse is plain text (html source code).

Comment: In that case, a significant portion of the code you posted is irrelevant. It would be helpful if you'd only include the *relevant* code. Okay, so how big is the response?

Comment: I have GET request from whatismyipaddress.com with format: http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/[ipaddress]

Comment: I wrote a basic class for more apps and websites. So problem POST clause is not necessary so its irrelevant.

Comment: That's my point - your question should include all the relevant information, but *only* relevant information.

Comment: So any ideas or solution help me in this case?

Comment: Well we still don't know how large the response is that's causing a problem - or how many times you're doing this... if you're calling this method *very* frequently (thousands of times per second), then maybe that's the problem. How quickly does the memory grow?

Comment: Well, i have said im geting html from whatismyipaddress.com. So response size around 11.74KB. This function is calling very rare. For testing i call it one time, when i call this function, immediately memory up to 1GB.

Comment: That sounds *very* unlikely to me - I think something else is going on. I've never seen *anything* like that. Try replacing the implementation of that method with something that just returns some boiler-plate HTML hard-coded into the method. Also, if you could reproduce the problem in a short but complete console app, that would help a lot.

Comment: Hmm, thank for your time Jon. I will try some another way to get more infomations on this error. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the .NET framework trying to intelligently manage memory for you... The memory reported in Task Manager is not actually the memory USED by your application but instead the memory ALLOCATED for use by your application. Try adding a `GC.Collect()` call to the end of this method - if it brings your memory back down to a relatively normal size, then you have nothing to worry about. If it doesn't, then you do in fact have a possible memory leak in the form of an object that is not releasing resource or otherwise.

Comment: Also don't leave the GC.Collect() method in place when you're done testing - it will slow down your application considerably.

Comment: No i mean the app will be slow down. I will never use GC.Collect(). I dont agree for this solution. I mean i have tried before. But the app too slow.

Comment: I'm asking you to try it to see what it does to your memory usage, thus confirming or denying the memory leak you're concerned about.